# MVC 5 Url rewrite exact match only

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting

I have a virtual directory on my site that no longer exisits /app

i want to redirect all requests to this to the home page but only if its exactly the url /app i tried the following but this also redirect the url /appointments

```
<rule name="RedirectToRoot" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="/app$" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="/" redirectType="Permanent"/>
</rule>
```

I know that the problem is with the regex im using but im not sure how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using this

```
<rule name="RedirectToRoot" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^app/(.*)" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent"/>
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below solution from MVC 5.

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        // Add the below 
                    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
// Add the below ^^

       routes.MapRoute(
                  name: "Default",
                  url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                  defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
              );
```

RouteConfig.cs you have to add the  routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();. Once done you can just mark [Route("MyDenfinedURL")] above action method

```
[Route("MyDenfinedURL")]
 public ActionResult MyAction()
        {
           //My do over the method    
            return View();
        }
```

Once this is done your job is over. Link of my source: http://www.dotnet-stuff.com/tutorials/aspnet-mvc/understanding-url-rewriting-and-url-attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-mvc5-with-examples